# How to script Chrome browser extension ID and permissions without downloading the extension?

Tags: python, google-chrome-extension, manifest, google-chrome-app

I am currently looking for a way to script a scraper that can fetch information from the HTML or webstore from the extension itself.

I want to be able to go to say for example "LastPass", be able to identify the extension ID (which looks like it is contained in a nonscne field) and download the extension permissions without installing the extension. I don't see a field containing the permissions on the web store itself.

We have a locked environment at my work place and we have to use a non work device just to be able to download an extension to tell what the permission levels are. FireFox has these permissions displayed on the store itself. I know the JSON file itself contains the permissions, but is there a way for someone who doesn't own the extension itself to go the web store and script a way to grab from maybe the HTML file somewhere?

I am a little lost on this, I am assuming Python might work best for this but I am not even sure where to started.

Comment: I think an open source extension downloader script/app should already exist so try searching. [Here's one](https://github.com/Rob--W/crxviewer) implemented as an extension.

Comment: I am trying to code my own and given we lock down extensions, I can't justify using an extension to do what I need to do. I am part of enterprise security control for my company. I am trying to figure out the code so I can script myself, I've tried googling it a few times but haven't found anything. I need to know the fields so I can edit it to the exact output I need for my script.

Comment: The link provided by @wOxxOm features an online version that allows you to view the source of an extension without downloading it, see [here](https://robwu.nl/crxviewer/)

Comment: Uhm... I've linked it so you can inspect the source code and see how it downloads other extensions.